# Before first headline at position XX in buffer - Unable to update org-clock-table

Tags: org-mode, org-clock, org-clock-table

I'm using emacs on Windows 7.
I have this file called `temp.org`, where I log all my project information.
I have clock entries project wise and I also had the clock table report. After the update that happened today (7-Sep-2017), I'm unable to update the clock table report using `C-c C-c`.

This is the message that is being displayed when I press `C-c C-x C-r`

> Before first headline at position 79 in buffer temp.org

I don't know what is wrong as I have not changed anything myself. In my .emacs file I had the following entry - but I commented it out to see if that was causing the problem.

```
;; Display the org clock sum in terms of hours and not in units of days 
;;(setq org-time-clocksum-format (quote (:hours "%d" :require-hours t :minutes ":%02d" :require-minutes t)))
```

As expected that did not solve the problem.
This is my [.emacs](https://pastebin.com/8kPrVcgk) file for reference.

This is how it looked before

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 4 :scope subtree
#+CAPTION: Clock summary at [2017-09-06 Wed 19:52]
| Headline                                    | Time     |        |       |       |
|---------------------------------------------+----------+--------+-------+-------|
| *Total time*                                | *447:58* |        |       |       |
|---------------------------------------------+----------+--------+-------+-------|
| Projects                                    | 447:58   |        |       |       |
| \_  D301 Cycle time reduction               |          |  37:09 |       |       |
| \_    Overview - KOM                        |          |        |  1:37 |       |
| \_    PCSD Development                      |          |        | 10:17 |       |
| \_      C_Add_ALARMS_AT [0/1]               |          |        |       | 10:17 |
| \_    Control coding                        |          |        | 25:15 |       |
| \_  FMTO - MRU for Propylene Loading...     |          | 172:19 |       |       |
| \_    IFDS & DI/DO Mismatch alarms          |          |        | 35:17 |       |
| \_    Alarms, DO & AO [0/12]                |          |        | 56:09 |       |
| \_    Simulation & Code check out           |          |        | 80:53 |       |
| \_      Line up checks                      |          |        |       | 39:26 |
| \_      Sim code checkout sheet             |          |        |       | 20:06 |
| \_  IP21 graphics update                    |          |  30:00 |       |       |
| \_    KR-26/27 OFCC + OXF + Staged Temp...  |          |        | 30:00 |       |
| \_  MET-2 Loss of Cooling implementation... |          |  10:42 |       |       |
| \_    General information:                  |          |        | 10:42 |       |
| \_  B-6610 Quat 188 LOPA Gap Closure        |          |  24:43 |       |       |
| \_  Poly 3 Project                          |          |  25:51 |       |       |
| \_  PBG-MEI Expansion Code -...             |          |  16:14 |       |       |
| \_  DCG Exception report                    |          |  37:28 |       |       |
| \_  EDC V800A/B Project                     |          |  45:30 |       |       |
| \_  B4 project                              |          |  25:22 |       |       |
| \_  Waterbatch Work Project                 |          |  19:48 |       |       |
| \_  MOD Sample project - Tic-Tac-Toe        |          |   2:52 |       |       |
| \_    Charter - Overall idea                |          |        |  1:12 |       |
| \_    PCSD Development                      |          |        |  1:40 |       |
#+END:
```

When I pressed `C-c C-c`, the table was gone and I got message mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use the `subtree` `scope` if you're in a headline.

Out of a headline you could use `:scope file` or `file-with-archives`.

Comment: But it was working before. I'll try adding a headline and top and revert

Comment: I would have commented on your accepted answer but I don't have enough sx
points.

There is no 'sub tree' scope, see http://orgmode.org/manual/The-clock-table.html
Since you pass an invalid scope (you could use `foobar` as well) it
just uses the current buffer.

For `subtree` you need to be in a headline.

Comment: You are right my friend. I selected your answer and deleted my answer. Thank you for taking the time to cite the reference from the manual. Now you have enough points to do what you like! Cheers!